# Display value of array from select input in Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have a set of data which has a city name and a value attributed to the city. When someone selects the city it should show the value. I know that I can get the selection by having `{{selected.value}}`. However, as I want to extract the value to later use it in a calculation (i.e. sum for example 30 to it), I try to calculate it using a computed value. My problem is that I can't seem to return the value or a part of the array. Whenever I have `return this.selected` I can see the entire selected array, but when I have `return this.selected.value` or `return.this.selected.name` I get nothing.

I'm quite new to vuejs so I'm not sure what am I missing.

```
    <template>
    <v-container fluid>
        <v-layout wrap align_center>
          <v-flex xs12 sm6>
            <v-select
              v-model="selected"
              :items="items"
              item-text= "city"
              item-value="value"
              :menu-props="{ maxHeight: '400'}"
              label="Select"
              hint="Pick your favorite states"
              multiple
              persistent-hint
              return-object
              single-line
            ></v-select>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex>
                  {{getselection}}

          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
        </v-container>

    </template>

    <script>

    export default {

        data () {
          return {
            text:'',
          selected: [],
          newsel: [],
          items:[
    {city: 'NY', value: 32},
    {city: 'Gent', value: 80},
    {city: 'Coimbra', value: 41}
     ]}
        },
  computed:{
    getselection(){
    return this.selected.value
    }
      },
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: You want only select one city ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim for now it doesn't really matter. What matters is that what's returned isn't the full array but either just city or just value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove `multiple` prop from `v-select` component in order to return one item:

```
 <v-flex xs12 sm6>
            <v-select
              v-model="selected"
              :items="items"
              item-text= "city"
              item-value="value"
              :menu-props="{ maxHeight: '400'}"
              label="Select"
              hint="Pick your favorite states"
             
              persistent-hint
              return-object
              single-line
            ></v-select>
```

See the Pen 
  [Vuetify Example Pen](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/xxKXEdY/) by boussadjra ([@boussadjra](https://codepen.io/boussadjra))
  on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

If you want to keep `multiple` prop the computed property could be like :

```
    getselection(){
    return !!this.selected.length ?this.selected[0].value:0;
    }
```

Comment: This works indeed, but how would it work for multiple selections?

Comment: but that returns multiple cities, you should access array via indexes or use one of its methods in order to make some logic

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your answer. If you remove the multiple prop from the v-select, you can't select then multiple options in the dropdown list.

Comment: if you keep multiple you should do something like `return this.selected[0].value`

Comment: That doesn't work. Actually even if you try it on your CodePen, the dropdown list disappears.

Comment: sorry you should do `return !!this.selected.length ?this.selected[0].value:0;` or `return !!this.selected[0]?this.selected[0].value:0;`

Comment: I'm really sorry but it still only shows the first selection. Not the multiple selections when I select lets say two options.

Comment: but it works here https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/xxKXEdY?&editable=true&editors=101

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198831/discussion-between-filipeteixeira-and-boussadjra-brahim).